# Continuouty of solution of IVP problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$ x'=f(t,x) $ , $x(t_0)=x_0$ is a IVP and $f$ is Lipschitz with respect to $t$ and $x$. Show that the solution is continuous with respect to $(t,t_0,x_0)$. 
I could show continuity with respect to $x_0$ but I didn't have any idea with respect to $t_0$.

I need a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Picard iteration gives furnishes uniform convergence. Assuming the initial condition is continuous, the Picard iterates are continuous, so the solution (i.e. the function $x(t)$ such that $x(0)=x_0,\frac{dx}{dt} = f(t,x(t))$) is continuous. So $x$ is continuous in $t$. 

The fact that $x$ is continuous in $t_0$ is trivial, because changing $t_0$ when $x_0$ is fixed just amounts to horizontally translating the graph of $x$. The technical matter is proving continuity with respect to $x_0$ (and, to a lesser extent, proving joint continuity in all three variables).

Comment: Also, to better follow the etiquette of this site, it would be appreciated if you wrote out what you have already proven (if you've shown continuity with respect to $x_0$, for example, write the proof out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert $t_0$ into an initial data by adding a new equation. Introduce a new variable $\tau$ and consider $t$ as a function of $\tau$. Consider the system
$$\begin{align}
x'(\tau)&=f(t,x)\\
t'(\tau)&=1
\end{align}$$
with initial conditions $t(0)=t_0$, $x(0)=x_0$.